# SVG is not taking the whole DIV space

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have an issue with my code, and search how the image at the center can take the whole space in the div ?
[image]

My actual code :

```
<div style="top:20%;position:absolute">
        <div id="a" style="display:block; 
                    width:240px;
                    height:160px;">
            <img src="UI/Button.svg">
        </div>
        <div id="b" style="display:none;
                    width:240px;
                    height:160px;">
            <img src="UI/Button_hover.svg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the SVG itself. It might have a path in a smaller area than its viewBox. To solve that you need to re-export it with trimmed sides up to the points where it touches the shape.